# I am trying to figure out how to pass a php variable that includes html code to another page using a form

Tags: php, forms

I have query results returned in an array on page1 and I want two of those results to pass and populate a form on page2. i have that part working except that one of the variables is a paypal button which includes html so it ends up displaying the button on page1 and does not let user click to page2. Besides displaying the button it displays " />. I need to know how, if possible, to pass the button details to become the "submit" button on page2. Thanks.

THIS IS PAGE1 CODE:

```
$results=mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($results) < 1) {
echo "<br>We are working on this trip's details.<br><br><h3 
style='color:#C8FE2E'>Check back soon!</h3>";
}   else {
$tripID    = 1; //temp var
$payButton = 2; //temp var

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
echo"Trip ID: "                 .$row[1].
    "<br>Date: "                .$row[3].
    "<br>Departs From: "        .$row[4].
    "<br>Departure Time: "      .$row[5].
    "<br>Arrives at Casino: "   .$row[6].
    "<br>Leaves at Casino: "    .$row[7].
    "<br>Arrives at Drop Off: " .$row[8].
    "<br>Drop Off Location: "   .$row[9].
    "<br>Price: $"              .$row[10].
    "<br><br>Trip Details: "    .$row[11]
    ;
$tripID    = $row[1];
$payButton = $row[14]; //should not display on this page
echo "";
} 
}

if(mysqli_num_rows($results) > 0) { 
?>
<br><br>
<form action="reserve-form.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="tripID" value="<?php echo $tripID; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" name="payButton" value="<?php echo $payButton;?>"/>
<button class='reg-btn' type="submit" name="clicked" style='border:none' >Register Now</button>
</form>

<?php
}else{
echo"";
}
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

AND THIS IS PAGE2 (where the button SHOULD display):

### Reserve your Seat

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Trip ID#</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="tripID" value="<?php     echo 
    $_POST['tripID']; ?>" readonly>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>First Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="firstName"     required >
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lastName"  required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Phone Number</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="phone" required>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label>Email Address</label>
    <input class="form-control" type="email" name="email"  required>
</div>

<center><input class="btn btn-success" id="submit_btn" type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
<img src="images/Spinner-gif.gif" class="ld_img" style="display:none;"/>
</center>
</form>
```

Comment: use `session` to do what you want

Comment: echo $_POST['payButton']; doesn't work? It's missing from the second part of the code you submitted.

Comment: on page1 or page2?